Are the elements of the eigenvector of the smallest real eigenvalue of an Z-matrix the same sign?
Let $\mathbf{A}=(\mathit{a}{_i}{_j}){_n}{_×}\mathit{_n}$, and
$$\mathit{a}{_i}{_j} \le 0,\quad i \neq j,i,j = 1,2,...,n$$
, then $\mathbf{A}$ is defined as a Z-matrix.

For example, an arbitrary Z-matrix:
$$\mathbf{A}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2.0854 & -0.3400 & -0.5096 & -0.0896
\newline
-2.0035 & 0.6889 & -2.3416 & -5.4027
\newline
-0.0067 & -0.6022 & -3.6640 & -0.0035
\newline
-2.7747 & -2.5461 & -0.9218 & 0.4837
\newline
\end{bmatrix}$$
All the eigenvalues are: $$4.2156,\quad 2.4024,\quad -2.3995,\quad -4.6245$$
The eigenvactor of the smallest eigenvalue $-4.6245$ is:$$[0.0788\quad 0.7336\quad 0.4622\quad 0.4919]{^T}$$
The question is:

If all the eigenvalues of a Z-matrix are real numbers, are the elements of the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue the same sign? And how to prove it?

The answer is essentially yes. The following is true: even if $A$ has complex eigenvalues, the eigenvalue that $A$ has with the smallest real part will necessarily be a real number, and this eigenvalue will necessarily have an associated eigenvector that has entries of the same sign. If we are additionally given that $A$ is irreducible, then there will be only one associated eigenvector and this eigenvector will have entries of the same sign.
Here's a proof.
Select any $k > \rho(A)$ (where $\rho(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of $A$). Note that $\lambda + k > 0$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$, $A + kI$ is a non-singular M-matrix, and that $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda$ if and only if it is an eigenvector of $A + kI$ associated with $\lambda + k$, which is true if and only if it is an eigenvector of $(A + kI)^{-1}$ associated with $\frac 1{\lambda + k}$.
Because $A + kI$ is an M-matrix, $(A + kI)^{-1}$ is non-negative and its eigenvalues have positive real parts. By the Perron Frobenius theorem, $(A + kI)^{-1}$ has $\mu = \rho[(A + kI)^{-1}]$ as an eigenvalue and $\mu$ must have an associated eigenvector $x>0$, and this eigenvector will be unique (up to a scalar multiple) if $(A + kI)^{-1}$ is irreducible, which holds if and only if $A$ is irreducible.
Because $\mu$ is the eigenvalue of $(A + kI)^{-1}$ with the largest absolute value, $\frac 1\mu$ is a real eigenvalue of $A + kI$ with the smallest absolute value (so it must also have the smallest real part), which means that $\lambda := \frac 1{\mu} - k$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ that has the smallest real part, and $\lambda$ has the positive vector $x$ as an associated eigenvector.

[+1] Once more, Perron-Frobenius is the key...
